# Tree Induction algorithm in gradient boosting

Tags: machine-learning, cart, boosting, loss-functions

In Gradient boosting tree algorithm we fit the negative gradients to the data via a regression tree to identify the regions in each iteration. We use least squares 
for fitting the tree to the negative gradients.

ie. for mth iteration

we fit the Tree that minimises,
gradient = [image] for loss function [image]

[image]

and given the regions [image] we find constants

[image]

and use these constants for updating the model.

So in building this Tree using greedy partitioning approach, ie. while scanning through the data points for splits and obtaining regions. Do we use constant estimates [image] , or do we use the CART algorithm(that uses average of the regions) or similar ones to build this tree?